# Validate an alphanumeric string that contains a fixed amount of non-consecutive periods

Tags: python, string, matching

I have a string that looks like that `"----.-------.-----.---"`.
Here `----` is any substring of random length, `.` is the separator and  the string can have a predetermined number of separator that I can dynamically change.

How can I use regex to validate that a string `new_string` matches this pattern?

I found some solution online, but none account for a random length substring and a dynamic number of separator.

Comment: Something like -+\.-+ might be a good start

Comment: so, basically you are just checking if a string contains only `-` and separators (`.` in this case), no other characters.

Comment: Something like `re.search(fr'^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){{{n_sep}}}$', new_string)` where `n_sep` is your dynamic number of delimiters maybe?

Comment: You do not need a regex to count specific chars in a string. `text.count('.') == 3` will do. What is the solution you found and used?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the count may not work in some cases. let's say `hello .. world` is the string in question and the number of occurrences for the separator is `2`. The `count` method will validate the string but the string doesn't match the desired pattern because the 2 separators follow each other.

Comment: @JvdV thanks I will check it out. is their a website where I can find a meaning for that command? I really struggle a lot with regex.

Comment: Not a problem at all, `text.count('.') == 3 and '..' not in text`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes you are right, this answers what i have written in the question. However, with your answer, I now think I may have not specified the problem perfectly. The substrings should only use alpha numerical characters. Is there a way to add another condition to take this into consideration?

Comment: Yes, `text.count('.') == 3 and '..' not in text and all(x.isalnum() for x in text.split('.'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in` operator but try to avoid `str.count` is possible, as `str.split` can also be used to account for this, and IIUC it does the same thing under the hood in any case, so probably worth it to eliminate what could be a duplicate iteration in our case.

Added my timings below just to double check this:

```py
from timeit import timeit

text1 = "aaaa.bb..ccc"
text2 = "aaaa.bbbbbbb.cccc.ddd"


def validate1(text):
    return text.count('.') == 3 \
           and '..' not in text \
           and all(x.isalnum() for x in text.split('.'))


def validate2(text):
    if '..' in text:
        return False

    parts = text.split('.')
    return len(parts) == 4 \
           and all(x.isalnum() for x in parts)


print('validate1:  ', timeit('validate1(text1); validate1(text2)', globals=globals()))
print('validate2:  ', timeit('validate2(text1); validate2(text2)', globals=globals()))

assert validate1(text1) is validate2(text1) is False
assert validate1(text2) is validate2(text2) is True
```

Note that, apparently even `all()` times can be slightly improved, by instead having it like:

```
len([1 for x in parts if x.isalnum()]) == 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
text.count('.') == 3 and '..' not in text and all(x.isalnum() for x in text.split('.'))
```

where

- `text.count('.') == 3` - checks if the string contains exactly three periods
- `'..' not in text` - disallows consecutive dots
- `all(x.isalnum() for x in text.split('.'))` - makes sure that all parts between dots consist of only alphanumeric chars.